# not possible to include js in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I wrote a simple program for including `js` in `jsp`, but its not working please help..

```html
<body>
  <script src="self1.js"></script>
  <div id="selfie">
    <form name="selfform" id="selfform">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username
            <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password
            <input type="password" name="pas" id="pas" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="log" id="log" 
                                    onclick="loginas()">Login</button>
          </td>/tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Not a Member? <a href="self2.jsp">Register Here</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

In my JavaScript I wrote: (`self1.js`)

```
function loginas(){
    alert("hi............");
}
```

I also tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/self1.js"></script>` But not working..please give me a solution??

Comment: Step:1 Check if there any error in your console..??

Comment: Please post your jsp file. are there any errors on the console log?

Comment: what is the path of your `js` file and your `jsp` file

Comment: path of js and jsp is..Webcontent/js/self1.js and Webcontent/jsp/self1.jsp  @Outlooker  Console shows no error

Comment: how should i upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step : Check whether there is any error in your page. You could find errors in your by checking your browser console tab(`Right Click->Inspect Element->Console Tab`).

2nd step : Correct it mate.. :)
In your case it is possibly not getting the js path correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/self1.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah its worked by the 2nd step.. thanku :) @Outlooker

Comment: @PriyankaU Also, Upvote the answers if you find it really useful !

Comment: There is a up & down triangle before the answer, just hit them and you can vote for it. Up Triangle refers to upvote and down triangle refers to downvote/negative voting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function (loginas) after your js is loaded.

To check it is working or not try to alert only in your js file like,

```
//self1.js
alert("hi............");
```

After updating you question, I found there may be issue that your DOM elements loaded first then your Js which will not work as your function should be defined before using it. So, you can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for binding event or use [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
// your js file code
$(function(){  // document ready shorthand
    function loginas(){
        alert("hi............");
    }
});
```

or use `on` like,

```
// your js file code
$(function(){  // document ready shorthand
    $('#log').on('click',function(){
        alert("hi............");
    }
});
```

And you HTML

```
<button type="button" name="log" id="log">Login</button>
```